# Simple Stack Implementation in Java not working

Tags: java, netbeans, stack

I have implemented a very basic Stack in Java which is giving strange errors never faced before.
The code is as follows:

```
public class Stack {
Node top;
int size;

public Stack() {top=null; size=0;}

public int pop() {
    if(top!=null) {
        int item = top.data;
        top = top.next;
        size--;
        return item;
    }
    return -1;
}

public void push(int data) {
    Node t = new Node(data);
    t.next = this.top;
    this.top = t;
    size++;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size<=0 ;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public int peek() {
    return top.data;
}

public void printStack() {
    Node n = this.top;
    int pos = this.getSize();
    while(pos>=0) {
        System.out.println("Position: " + pos + " Element: " + n.data);
        if(pos>0) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        pos--;
    }
}
}

class Node {
public int data;
public Node next;

Node(int d) {data=d; next=null;}

public int getData() {return data;}
}

class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.push(9);s.push(2);s.push(7);s.push(3);s.push(6);s.push(4);s.push(5);
    System.out.println("Size is: " + s.getSize());
    //s.printStack();
    for (int i=0; i<s.getSize(); i++) {
        System.out.print(s.pop()+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I have tested thoroughly and found that the push operation works perfectly with all the 7 elements being pushed in the correct sequence with proper next/top pointer set.
But, when I try to pop out all the elements, then only it pops the top-4 (5-4-6-3) leaving the other ones.
Then, I tried to perform a printStack with the above method and there it gives random NullPointerException errors as follows:

```
run:
Position: 7 Element: 5
Position: 6 Element: 4
Position: 5 Element: 6
Position: 4 Element: 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Position: 3 Element: 7
Position: 2 Element: 2
    at Stack.printStack(Stack.java:58)
Position: 1 Element: 9
    at Tester.main(Stack.java:95)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

These errors doesn't make sense to me and moreover by introducing some more print statements in push() and printStack() for tracing it starts to throw more random exceptions.
The errors are completely non-deterministic for each run and gives different patterns in different machines.
I have traced one complete run with Netbeans debugger and found no errors!

Your help is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it has nothing to do, but I'd declare pop and push methods synchronized. And I'd also verify that top is not null in peek method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first in `printStack()` method:

```
while (pos > 0) {
```

instead of

```
while (pos >= 0) {
```

because your 0 position is always `null`

and in main:

```
int size = s.getSize();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.getSize(); i++)
```

because your stack size decreasing with each iteration.

Comment: Your both points are correct and fixed the problems. For the first point, position moving from 1 to s.getSize() is understood, but in that situation the error should be thrown at the last iteration when it falls out of the bound. But as seen from some outputs, the NullPointerException errors are appearing in random iterations and some of them in the beginning and middle iterations. Why so?

Comment: I really have no idea, why the exception stack trace start being printed before the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<s.getSize(); i++)
```

is causing the stack size to decrease for each pop and i will increase for each pop. By the time it is done with 4 pops, stack size equals value of i. Hence, print stack stops in the middle.

Replacing the above for loop with the following

```
for (; !s.isEmpty();)
```

will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

printStack() was failing as you were not checking for n being null. Following code fixes this issue.

`public void printStack() {
        Node n = this.top;
        int pos = this.getSize();

```
    System.out.println("Stack Size is " + pos);
    while(n!=null) {
        System.out.println("Position: " + pos + " Element: " + n.data);
            n = n.next;
        pos--;
    }
}`
```